# Oracle Function .How to compare previous value with Current value

Tags: oracle, function

My Source Data

---

```
ename   Age
BAL          N
BAL          Y
BAL          Y
YUV          N
YUV          Y
NAR          N
```

Logic

---

if ( (ename <> Previous_Ename  or Previous_AGE='N' ) then AGE = as is
Else AGE='Y'

Could you please let me know how to code this using Oracle funcaiton? i tried but in all case it not showing the desired result set.

i used

---

```
create or replace function () RETURN
    VARCHAR2
IS
      previous_name VARCHAR2 (9) := 'DUMMY';
      previous_age  VARCHAR2 (9) := 'Z';
    BEGIN
    For cur_rec in (select ename, age from tablename order by ename) LOOP
    if ( cur_rec.ename <> previous_ename or previous_age ='N')
        then return cur_rec.age;   /** it is populating the result set with only "N"***/
            else return 'Y';
        end if;
                previous_ename :=ename;   /*** not sure whether this assignment is correct- im trying to assignt current value as previous value for next row reference.****/
                    previous_age :=age;      /*** not sure whether this assignment is correct****/
        END LOOP;
    END
```

REsult im getting:- actually the result should be same as Source for this data scenerio

---

```
ename   Age
BAL           N
BAL           N
BAL           N
YUV           N
YUV           N
NAR           N
```

Comment: What is the "previous ename"? There is no inherent order to a table so you need something else to order by. How do you determine this? Do you have a timestamp in your table etc, etc?

Comment: For Cur_rec in ( select ename, age from tablename order by ename, age)LOOP.
im ordering it when inside the for loop. sorry i missed to list tat earlier.

Comment: But age is NULL (according to your input data) so your "order" is essentially random, which will be incorrect if you have any other columns in the table (you might not have any other columns? But, if that's the case then I'm not certain what you're trying to achieve here).

Comment: Hello Ben, there was some formatting issue earlier. not i edited with reult set and the full-code. basically here age is just (Y or N).

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve here (at all)... or why

The problem is that you're trying to to this in a function but you're *returning* the something almost immediately. By your order logic (in the comments) the first value will always be `N` because that's the first value in the ORDER BY. For *every* record in your table this will be true.

Use a MERGE statement instead:

```
merge into tmp n
using ( select rowid as rid
             , ename
             , age
             , lag(age) over ( partition by ename order by age ) as lag_age
          from tmp
               ) o
   on ( n.rowid = o.rid )
 when matched then
      update
         set n.age = case when lag_age is null then age
                          when lag_age = 'N' then age
                          else 'Y' 
                     end
       ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04632/1)

Comment: hello Ben. to  clarify your doubt. the Source is a physical table. i do have another "final" target table which along with ename, age, has 50 more colulmns all remaining columns are derived for 20 other tables. to calculate or to identify "age" im using the above Source table. in the actual 'master" store procedure whic is used to load the "Final" Target table. i will left join Source table and will invoke a Function to calculate the age based on the logic. mentioned.

Comment: You can't then @balaji; it's impossible as you don't have a unique set of columns (or at least not one you've divulged - note I had to resort to rowid). This means your result is essentially random.

Comment: Hello Ben..In case if i have a TimeStamp column/any unique column added to the existing  can i do that still thru funcations?  if so could you please let me know what change i need to make in my above funcations?